# MSXML4 and setting the encoding string

Tags: c++, msxml4

I using MSXML4 to generate a XML.

I'm trying to set the encoding value to UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
const _bstr_t k_XML_Tag_Name ("xml");
const _bstr_t k_Processing_Tag_Name ("version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"");

MSXML2::IXMLDOMProcessingInstructionPtr pProccessingInstruction = m_pXmlDoc->createProcessingInstruction(k_XML_Tag_Name, k_Processing_Tag_Name);

HRESULT result = m_pXmlDoc->appendChild(pProccessingInstruction);
```

`result` is always `S_FALSE` and the preprocessing string is:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

So, why isn't the encoding string showing up?

Comment: Is this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msxml/thread/1726e6d6-21a5-4853-8a85-1dc7b068afba

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the xml to a file you should see the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` declaration. However, according to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx), when you use the `XML` property of the document the declaration returned does not contain the encoding, which seems to be by design. Is this the behavior you are encountering? The article states that:

> This is normal. The reason it did this
>   is so that you can turn around and
>   call LoadXML with this string and it
>   will work. If it does not do this,
>   LoadXML will fail with the error
>   message: "Switch from current encoding
>   to specified encoding not supported."